# Advise me a book please

Tags: book-recommendation

I am in need of book on coordinates and arithmetic progression, for level like:

 $3x-y=6$
 $3x+4y+9=0$

Find meet point this two lines, and meet points with $x,y$ axis, and area of triangle formed by this two lines and $x$ axis
 
OR 
Draw the curve represnted by$y=x^2+4x-21$ stating and showing clearly the point where the curve turns and the points where it meets the axes
 
Progression: 
Sum of $a_1$ and $a_5$ is equal to $\frac{5}{3}$, and  $a_3*a_4$ is equal to $\frac{65}{72}$. Find $S_{17}$.

Comment: Higher Algebra by Hall and Knight and Coordinate Geometry by Loney , both available free at www.archive.org, for drawing graphs "Plotting Graphs" by Shilov at www.mirtitles.org

Comment: My thanks to you, that books really helpfull

Comment: I would suggest *Алгебра, I, II части* by Kiselev. Alternatively, have a look at the books by Makarychev here: http://sovietime.ru/algebra You'll want the old grade 6 and 7 books (or new grade 7 and 8).